# Setting active class on menu link items

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with setting an active class to the menu. Here is my code:

```
<ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'index.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="index.php">Эхлэл</a></li>
    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'product.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="product.php">Бүтээгдэхүүн</a></li>
    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'about.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="about.php">Бидний тухай</a></li>
    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == 'contact.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="contact.php">Холбоо барих</a></li>
</ul>
```

And result is:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in E:\xampp\htdocs\tgnm\header.php on line 131**

What am i doing wrong ? and this code will be work ?

Comment: which line is 131

Comment: that `ul` starting from 131 in `header.php`

Comment: you have not closed the "(" before the base name function.

Comment: You need to add the close ")" bracket here. http://prntscr.com/q3r9f9

Comment: Thanks. Error gone but active class not works :)

Comment: For that, you have to echo the value of "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" and let me what value is returned?

Comment: `tgnm/about.php` gives me those.

Comment: Now i understand if is it on remote server it should be works fine cause my server now `http://localhost:81/tgnm/about.php` something that didn't work xD

Comment: Please check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, You have to complete bracket add to before "==" this location. 
Please update the below code.

```
                <ul class="main-nav nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="index.php">Эхлэл</a></li>
                    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'product.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="product.php">Бүтээгдэхүүн</a></li>
                    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="about.php">Бидний тухай</a></li>
                    <li class="<?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php') ? 'active' : ''; ?> "><a href="contact.php">Холбоо барих</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: For your information, if you want to check php syntax error. You can use this online tool. https://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.